# MS Excel is pasting tab-delimited strings from React-Copy-To-Clipboard into just one cell

Tags: excel, reactjs, copy-paste

I'm trying to use [React-Copy-To-Clipboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-copy-to-clipboard) to create a copy-to-clipboard feature for my app, which will copy some data rows from a table, to the clipboard, in a tab-delimited format that Excel will paste correctly.

i.e. joining each row item with '\t', and a '\n' at the end of each row.

(Apologies to anyone offended by my use of coffeeScript)

```js
convertToTabSeparated : (rows) ->
    dataRows =
    rows
      .map (row) -> row.join('\t')
      .join('\n')
    return dataRows
```

The output from this pastes in looking absolutely as it should:
- on the console
- in a text editor
- and even when using 'paste special > paste values' in Excel Desktop (or a similar special paste in Google Spreadsheet).

The **problem** is that a simple, non-special paste into Excel results in all the values being pasted into one cell.

Muddying the waters more, when I use the Cloud version of MS Excel, this isn't the case - it works absolutely fine with a regular paste.

Another thing: when I paste into a text editor, then copy again and re-paste the result into Excel, it works fine in all cases.

So: does anyone know of any character/formatting issues that might come out of the react copy to clipboard component that results in the \t and \n not being registered properly when doing a regular paste?

---

**Solution found, sort of:**
It seems the React library in question copies to clipboard the data with a surrounding html  element, which Excel's not keen on.
I decided to add my own copy to clipboard DOM method, as follows, using the same approach but with a textarea instead of a span, and with a slightly different selection method. Seems to work great.

```
copyToClipboard : (text) ->
    textArea = document.createElement("textarea")
    textArea.style.position = 'fixed'
    textArea.style.top = 0
    textArea.style.left = 0
    textArea.style.width = '2em'
    textArea.style.height = '2em'
    textArea.style.padding = 0
    textArea.style.border = 'none'
    textArea.style.outline = 'none'
    textArea.style.boxShadow = 'none'
    textArea.style.background = 'transparent'
    textArea.value = text
    document.body.appendChild(textArea)
    textArea.select()

    try
      successful = document.execCommand 'copy'
      msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful'
      log 'Copying text command was ' + msg
    catch err
      alert 'Unable to copy'

    document.body.removeChild textArea
```

Comment: Your solution worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Excel expects as delimiter the delimiter you used last time when using "test to columns". Try splitting the pasted table into columns manually once and try again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response - but what I'm trying to achieve is a way to output clipboard content from my app that will ALWAYS paste correctly without having to change any settings.